# Google CSE v2 filter sample

Tags: filter, google-custom-search

I tried to look everywhere for a sample that explains how filters can be added via javascript or querstring to search results. CSE v2 not 1.

Something similar to https://www.nrd.gov/jobSearch/list/jobSearch?q=test&moc=&location=&_includeNearbyCities=&datePosted=31&title=&hiringOrganization=&employmentType=full+time&baseSalary=&experienceRequirements=&qualifications=&submit=Find+Jobs&order=asc&sort=jobposting-dateposted where you can see filtering options on the left

Thanks